# Performance difference between vector and list

Tags: c++

I am using the bubble sort function below and the Container type is defined with either

```
typedef std::vector<int> Container;
```

or

```
typedef std::list<int> Container;
```

I compile the code like this

/usr/bin/g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -c -o bubble_sort.o bubble_sort.cc

When the container is a list the function can sort 10000 integers in about
3.2 seconds. When the container is a vector the function takes about 4.6 seconds for the same sort.

My question is why the performance is so much worse for vectors and what tools are best for digging into problems like this?

```
void bubbleSort(Container& randomIntegers)
{
    bool swapPerformed;
    do
    {
        swapPerformed = false;
        Container::iterator iter2 = randomIntegers.begin();
        Container::iterator iter1 = iter2++;

        while (iter2 != randomIntegers.end())
        {
            if (*iter1 > *iter2)
            {
                std::swap(*iter1, *iter2);
                swapPerformed = true;
            }
            iter1++;
            iter2++;
        }

    }
    while (swapPerformed);
}
```

Comment: Almost every single C++ performance question on SO has someone ask "what optimization settings are you compiling under".  So why didn't you mention your build flags?

Comment: Ah, I'll add that. Thanks.

Comment: Don’t bother with performance analysing C++ code without optimization turned on. You should have read Yakk’s comment as “make sure optimization is enabled”

Comment: With GCC 8 and -O3 on Wandbox, a vector takes about 150 ms and a list takes about 700-900 ms with single runs. Clang 6 is more like 160 and 1100.

Comment: OKay, that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardJohnson -- The difference is even more noticeable if you had used Visual Studio, where "debug mode" adds iterator and bounds checking to the standard containers.  Adding compiler, compiler version, and build flags is a prerequisite when asking performance questions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Also possible with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` with libstdc++.  A vector with -O3 jumped to 25 seconds.

Comment: @chris -- Thanks, good to know.